# Retrieving value from XSL element tag

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
        <SecurityRole>
            <ID lid="lid://infor.xm.xm_xm">XM-ER: Role</ID>
            <Description>Role for ER creation</Description>             
        </SecurityRole>
```

I want to retrieve lid in ID element and store it in lid tag.

```
<xsl:for-each select="SecurityRole">
        <lid>
        </lid>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a simple template (no need of for loop)

```
<xsl:template match="SecurityRole">
    <lid><xsl:value-of select="ID/@lid"/></lid>
</xsl:template>
```